# How to setup Assembla Subversion for private project - new to source control

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn, assembla

I've used source control in the past to commit code, in 2009 when I was working with .NET framework 2.0. I have been away from programming for around 3 years. Now I am trying to do some Win 8 programming in C# and need to setup source control for my private project.

I came across Visual SVN for VS 2012 which integrates source control within VS. Can anybody please guide me to a doc which gives me step by step instructions on how to setup SVN for my private project? I've though of using Assembla because it seems free.

Comment: What kind of instructions do you want? Did you check the getting started at http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/getting-started/?

Comment: I will suggest to you to give a hand on this first and post here if you are facing some issues. This question is too generic to answer

Answer (score 6):

1. Download and install Tortoise SVN - http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html
2. Install Visual SVN
3. Register a new Assembla Account
4. Setup Assembla Repository (Note that the free account only gives you 500MB of space)

After you have set up your repository, make a note of your URL of your repo (e.g. https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/RooiWillie/)

Next you need to determine a space on your hard drive where you will place your source (e.g. C:\Subversion\RooiWillie). Create the directory (if you have not yet) and right click. Highlight TortoiseSVN and click Repo-Browser.

Enter the URL of your repo.

You will be prompted for your credentials, just use your Assembla credentials.

And that is it, you can now add files (your VS2012 solution/s) to your repository and check out a working copy.

After you have installed VisualSVN, you will notice a VisualSVN menu in Visual Studio. It piggybacks onto Tortoise, so the dialogs will be similar. You should be able to get your way around.

A good resource will be the tortoise docs:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/latest/download

*edit - Link Updated

Comment: Dear @RooiWillie, when i following these above steps, I gettin this error, please help me >> http://bayanbox.ir/id/1343133796436885403?view

Comment: Do you make use of Ankhsvn?

Comment: I'm used from VisualSVN, but my problem solved by using `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: Ah fantastic, sorry about the late reply though!